# changing the format change the reference number, how do I force to keep the same reference number?

Tags: cross-referencing, ieeetran, acm, ieee-style, back-referencing

I'm changing the format from IEEE 2 column to acm computing survey. But changing the format also change the order of references. How can I keep the past order of references and maintain the same order in the new formatted text?

Comment: The ordering of the references is controlled directly by the bibliography style, i.e., the argument of the `\bibliographystyle` directive. Now, the document class you use may automatically load a specific bibliography style. If that's the case, it's a conscious design decision of the creator(s) of the document class. It may be ill-advised to hack the document class file to impose a different bibliography style.

Comment: At any rate, please edit your posting to provide more, or rather more specific, information as to the document class you employed so far and the document class you will be using going forward.

Comment: Changing the bibliography style works for me!!! Thanks...